# Django add a relation between the user and the selected articles

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a simple model Article. The model is:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    text = models.TextField()
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I have also login, and likes, every user has favorite articles.
I make new model:

```
class LikeArticle(models.Model):
    article = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In view we have

```
def articleLike(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        article_id = request.POST['id']
        article_like = LikeArticle(
           article=article_id,
           user=request.user
        )
        article_like.save()
```

And when we want to see all favorite articles

```
def favorite(request):
    favorite_list = LikeArticle.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'article/favorite.html', {'articleList': favorite_list})
```

But now its return me id article and username, how I can filter and choose from
Article.objects.all()

Is my logic correct?
Maybe I need to do everything differently?

Comment: Why are you not using a foreign key from `LikeArticle` to `Article` as you do with `User`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link `LikeArticle` and `Article` via foreign key:

```
class LikeArticle(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table mapping users to articles has an `article` field that is only an integer column, not a foreign key. It has no relationship to your articles table beyond the two sharing a name.

What you're doing is called a many-to-many relationship and Django actually has a special field called [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) that manages the intermediate table for you (so you don't have to create `LikeArticle`):

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    text = models.TextField()
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    favorited_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="favorite_articles")
```

Now, you can do something like this:

```
def favorite(request):
    favorite_list = request.user.favorite_articles.all()
    return render(request, 'article/favorite.html', {'articleList': favorite_list})
```

And the reverse relationship: `Article.objects.get(id=123).favorited_by.all()`